# Unable to place a layout at the bottom after scroll view

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, uiview, scrollview

I am unable to place a layout at the bottom after a scroll view. Please help. 
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_call"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_phone_main"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/call_us_tab"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Call Us"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#5488B8" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/message_tab"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/msg"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#5488B8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_share"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/share_tab"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_name_detail_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_map"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Show Map"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:id="@+id/rating_bar_pro_detail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        style="@style/foodRatingBar"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_nearby"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_specialization"
                        android:text="Specialization: "
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list_specialization"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_education"
                        android:text="Education:"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list_education"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_experiences"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Experiences:"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list_experience"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#5488B8"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#00427F"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should place your scrollview in ViewGroups like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout with layout-wegith.

Comment: can you put screen shot what exactly want to do and what you get

Comment: @VishalHalani  I want  the linear layout to be sticked at the bottom which contains 3 image views and text and above it scroll view works, but it is not happening so. I am unable to set it in the proper way

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas see my answer below it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this, this will fix your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas May I know why did you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use root layout as RelativeLayout and the view you want to align bottom that's add this line:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and give your scroll view any variable size rather than wrap_content

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_name_detail_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <RatingBar
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/rating_bar_pro_detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    style="@style/foodRatingBar"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_nearby"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_specialization"
                    android:text="Specialization: "
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/list_specialization"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_education"
                    android:text="Education:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/list_education"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_experiences"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Experiences:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/list_experience"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_call"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_phone_main"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/call_us_tab"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Call Us"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#5488B8" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/message_tab"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/msg"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#5488B8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_share"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/share_tab"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` at parent and then you can place items up and down to each other like

which view you want below to another view you can use this

```
android:layout_below="@+id/yourview"
```

and for view you want above to other you can use this

```
android:layout_above="@+id/yourview"
```

here is a sample

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView">
        <!-- some stuff in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this hopefully this is what you wanted

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  


     android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
            />

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_name_detail_info"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Name"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
                        android:text="address"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:id="@+id/rating_bar_pro_detail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:numStars="5"

                        />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_nearby"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_specialization"
                        android:text="Specialization: "
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <ListView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/list_specialization"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_education"
                        android:text="Education:"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <ListView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/list_education"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_experiences"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Experiences:"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <ListView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/list_experience"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5"
            >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_call"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:background="#000000">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_phone_main"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/name_top"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/call"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Call Us"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#5488B8" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/name_top"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/msg"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#5488B8" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_share"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:weightSum="2"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/name_top"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#5488B8"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#00427F"
        android:listSelector="#898989"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please update version of a recyclerview library in gradle file :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

It should solve your issue.

Due to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772), wrap_content not used to work on recyclerview before this version.

Comment: The is not about **RecycleView** its about **ScrollView**.